# DNN Blog Module how to change the blog post order

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

In DotNetNuke(DNN) Blog module, how can I change the order of the blog posts? by default the most recent blog entry would always be displayed on top. How can I change the order of the blog entries?

Comment: What order are you trying to get?

Comment: I would like to give the user the option to sort the blog posts in ascending or descending order depending on the blog post date. By default the Blog module would display the most recent blog entries on top. I wish to customize the blog by giving the option to the user to sort it by the date so that the oldest blog entries could appear on top. Any thoughts on how I should proceed with this? thanks.

Comment: Without doing some backend work the only real option is to have a sort via jQuery or something - or you could write some sort of Razor module to display it how you would like.

Comment: On which version have you done modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require that you download the source code of the blog module and add this feature yourself.  It would require at least one UI element, such as a toggle sort link, and modifying the DAL to respond to the UI elements actions.